# How to share a CSV file on Android Pie?

Tags: java, android

On [Android Pie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Pie), I want to share my CSV file to any sharing app such as Bluetooth or email, etc... it runs in lower version but in 9.0 it won't

```
  final String test = "content://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                                   + "/Download" + "/" + "ProgressivePayment.csv";
  Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
  sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(test));
  sharingIntent.setType("text/csv");
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with"));
```

Comment: How does it *not work* in Android Pie? Does it throw any `Exception` or does it simply not open the share view?

Comment: it will open the share view  but it wont read the file but if on lower version it will read and sended

Comment: Any warnings or errors in logcat?

Comment: fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: Then check [this question and its answer(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)...

Comment: that question is for image but i want to share a csv file

Comment: Maybe it is, but it is about *the same error message / `Exception`* and may be helpful...

Comment: yeah i'm actually trying that solution

Comment: it says unable to attach file now

Answer (score 0):

> it runs in lower version

It is possible that there is some poorly-written app that incorrectly handles `EXTRA_STREAM` and accidentally handles that broken `Uri`. Or, [as Martin Zeitler points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357667/how-to-share-a-csv-file-on-android-pie/56359357#comment99322402_56359357), perhaps there is a strange pre-installed `ContentProvider` on the device that happens to honor your broken `Uri`. Most apps on most devices will crash when attempting to use that `Uri`, as there will be no matching `ContentProvider`.

You can [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) to *correctly* create a `content` `Uri` that will serve up some file that you control.

Comment: without `FileProvider` it might only complain that an `Uri` is being leaked beyond the scope of the application (recently had this problem and can only confirm the suggestion).

Comment: @MartinZeitler: I expect it to crash with a failed lookup of the authority string. There is no requirement that there be a `ContentProvider` with a `storage` authority that knows how to handle the rest of that.